# How to group by and sum in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables like following one
I'd like to extract customers who has `product=a`

```
customer product score
A          a      10
A          b      20 
A          c      30
B          b      10 
B          c      20
C          a      30
C          c      40
```

And then, I'd like to `sum`the score by each customer.

```
customer product score
A          a      10
A          b      20 
A          c      30
C          a      30
C          c      40
```

Therefore my desired result is like following
Are there any way to achieve this?

```
customer score
A         60
C         70
```

My work is like below. I'd like to know next step

```
SELECT t1.customer, t1.product, t1.score
  FROM yourTable t1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM yourTable t2
                WHERE t2.customer = t1.customer
                  AND t2.product = 'a');
```

Thanks

Comment: because B don't have `product=a`. thanks

Comment: thanks i didnt fully read the question, my apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need an aggregate (GROUP BY) and a SUM(t1.score)

```
SELECT t1.customer, sum(t1.score) as summed_score
  FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM yourTable t2 
               WHERE t2.customer = t1.customer 
                 AND t2.product = 'a')
GROUP BY t1.customer
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be using `HAVING` Clause with aggregation :

```
SELECT customer, SUM(score) AS score
  FROM t
 GROUP BY customer 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN product = 'a' THEN 1 END)>0
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=865be5cd6d2fabd73d6994b36e40d23c)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple aggregation

```
select customer, sum(score)
from tablename t where exists (select 1 from tablename t1 where t.customer=t2.customer and t1.product='a')
group by customer
```

Answer (score 1):

**Now you just have to use group by() & sum()**

```
SELECT t1.customer, sum(t1.score) 
FROM  my_table t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table t2 WHERE t2.customer = t1.customer AND t2.product = 'a') 
group by t1.customer;
```

**or**

```
SELECT t1.customer, sum(t1.score) 
FROM  my_table t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table t2 WHERE t2.customer = t1.customer AND t2.product = 'a') 
group by t1.customer 
order by t1.customer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query, just need to check the customer column in the sub query of same table where product = 'a'

```
select customer, sum(score) as score from table_name where customer in
(select customer from table_name where product = 'a')
group by customer;
```